# How can i change kivy window position using Window.top and Window.left

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Someone questioned similar thing , answer was given but without example for it thus i am unable to solve this simple solution checked documentation and was unable to understand

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

How to do this :

```
Config.set('graphics','position','custom')

Config.set('graphics','left',500)
Config.set('graphics','top',10)
```

using Window.left and Window.top

```
Window.size = (1920, 150)
Window.top =????????
Window.left =??????????
```

I don't know the syntax or my kivy installation is bugged

Person in chat @inclement did not understand this question... so here is full example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import threading
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Hello(FloatLayout):
    
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        super(Hello,self).__init__(**kwargs)       
        Window.size = (600, 150)
        #INSERT Window.left and under it Window.top to position this window on coordinates 50,50 on the top left of the screen
        

class Example(App):
    def build(self):
        return Hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run();
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried?

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear :)

Comment: Have you tried setting `Window.left` to a value and seeing what happens? Does it not do anything?

Comment: Sir i tried adding values and i get all kinds of errors.  "TypeError: an integer is required"
and others its random cuz i can write many things to test this.. If you know how this command works or syntax you can simply tell me or just do it in the example above for example : Window.left = (50) Window.top =  (50) and give me the answer (obviously my example here gives error and is incorrect) 
You can change all code above as long as you accomplish this : Moving the window position at coordinates 50,50 (or some other coordinates) USING Window.left and Window.top for position of window

Comment: I would suggest trying `Window.left = 50` and `Window.top = 50`, but this seems so obvious (indeed as you even wrote it n your comment) that I assume you've tried it and it doesn't work? In that case, post what goes wrong.

Comment: My App freezes and there is nothing happening inside terminal after adding values Window.left = 50 and Window.top = 50,

Comment: What happens if you try running that code later in the app, e.g. after a few seconds?

Answer (score 4):

Found out the answer i had problems with my code rather than syntax or installation of Kivy.

Answer to above example is simply inserting:

```
Window.top = 50
Window.left = 50
```

I had problems somewhere else in my code so i was very confused and wanted quick check with someone.

Feedback for @inclement: if you went with your thought answer is you were right on the money. That was the syntax and what i was looking for. You asking me additional questions was more confusing than helpful, intention of helping appreciated non the less =)